# Can I add multiple columns at once with a Power Query M custom formula?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, custom-function

As a business analyst, I need to repeatedly use cost and revenue data points to create different variants of a margin result.

I am trying to come up with a reusable piece of code that I can use and share so that everyone in my team can create their own margin analysis in power query with a few simple clicks.

Once I know how to do this, I can use the same logic on a plethora of other applications, so I'm looking forward to everyione's ideas!

I tried to write a custom function in Power Query M that would take two columns and return the results in more than one column.

The following piece of code does not work. It throws an error saying it expected an EoF Token in line 6:

```
(Cost as number, Revenue as number) =>
let
    margin_absolute = Revenue - Cost,
    margin_relative = Cost / Revenue
in
    margin_absolute
in
    margin_relative
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong approach?

Comment: Do you want the function to return multiple values, or to add columns to table?

Comment: I want to add columns to a table. One Column for margin_absolute and one column for margin_relative.

Comment: It is just as easy to have them add two custom columns, as to have them add the function, and then add code that references the function

Comment: That is true for this particular instant. I do, however, have some other use cases that require adding eight columns based on two variables each. I would like to automate the adding of columns so as to reduce sources of error within the released document. And once I understand how to do this for two columns, I will be able to apply the same logic to the more cumbersome use case.

Comment: Glad you got what you needed, but frankly its just easier to pass the entire table to the function and let the function Table.AddColumns() for 8 different calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work thanks to the below Chat GPT answer. I successfully tested the code.

"It looks like there are a couple of issues with your Power Query M code. The primary issue is with the structure of your `let...in` expression. You've closed the `let...in` block prematurely and attempted to return two values directly, which is not supported in the way you've structured it. Power Query M functions can only return a single value, but this value can be a record or a table, which can effectively contain multiple values (or columns).

Here's how you can modify your function to return both `margin_absolute` and `margin_relative` as a record:

```m
(Cost as number, Revenue as number) =>
let
    margin_absolute = Revenue - Cost,
    margin_relative = if Revenue <> 0 then Cost / Revenue else null
in
    [Margin_Absolute = margin_absolute, Margin_Relative = margin_relative]
```

In this revised version:

- The function takes `Cost` and `Revenue` as inputs.
- It calculates `margin_absolute` and `margin_relative`.
- It returns a record containing both `Margin_Absolute` and `Margin_Relative`.
- I've added a check to prevent division by zero in the `margin_relative` calculation.

To use this function in your Power Query editor:

1. **Create the Function**: Copy the revised function into a new blank query to create the function.
2. **Invoke the Function**: To use this function, you'll need to call it for each row of your table. Suppose your table has columns named `Cost` and `Revenue`. You can add a custom column to call this function:

   ```m
   Table.AddColumn(yourTableName, "Margin", each (Cost as number, Revenue as number) =>
   let
       margin_absolute = Revenue - Cost,
       margin_relative = if Revenue <> 0 then Cost / Revenue else null
   in
       [Margin_Absolute = margin_absolute, Margin_Relative = margin_relative], type record)
   ```
3. **Expand the Record**: After adding the custom column, you'll have a column of records. You can expand this to create two new columns, `Margin_Absolute` and `Margin_Relative`, by using the "Expand Column" feature in the Power Query editor.

This approach allows you to encapsulate the margin calculations in a single function, which can be reused across multiple queries or shared with your team."